# How to over come LinkedHashMap is a raw type. References to generic type LinkedHashMap<K,V> should be parameterized issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, generics

```
LinkedHashMap lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    lHashMap.put("One", new Integer(1));
    lHashMap.put("Two", new Integer(2));
    lHashMap.put("Two", new Double(2.00));
```

this works but eclipse gives me the warning so if i use

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
```

i can only use string inside the hash map how to overcome this.

Comment: LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>(); should work fine

Comment: Isn't this the point of generics? What else would you want as keys?

Comment: No, Integer will not work, note that he uses a Double

Comment: for some values i need string too , lHashMap.put("One", "two");

Comment: See revised response - use Object then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also need Strings, then just:

```
LinkedHashMap<String,Object> lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
```

(edited - changed `Number` to `Object`)

Comment: or `LinkedHashMap<String,Number> lHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>()` if using Java 7.